# Using keypress in android

Tags: java, android, keypress

I am creating an android application, a converter. Every time I am going to press any number, I want it to be displayed automatically on a textfield. I don't know how to use the keypress in android application. Is it just like using keypress in a simple java program, let's say ran on netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

Um ...

```
public class MainActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(new EditText());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is all I can come up with from your not very specific question. And If you'd post the code you have so far ...that were great.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.. but i think you are saying that your layout contain a `EditText` and `TextView`,  when user type in a number in EditText at same time the TextView should also set the same text at rumtime. if this is your requirement then you can do it as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle b)
   {
      super.onCreate(b);
      setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
      TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
      EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
      et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                tv.setText(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
            }
        });
        }
   }
```